# A struct can be created inside a class?

Tags: c#, asp.net

A struct can be created inside a class like the code below?  what is the correct way to create a struct is usefull created inside a class? and other question is if the properties of a struct must be declared with getters and setters like this public int Strength {get; set;} or is ok the way it is in the code shown below?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace createStructs
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

        }
        struct Coffee
        {
            /*properties*/
            public int Strength;
            public string Bean;
            public string CountryOfOrigin;
            /*constructor*/
            public Coffee(int strength, string bean, string countryOfOrigin)
            {
                this.Strength = strength;
                this.Bean = bean;
                this.CountryOfOrigin = countryOfOrigin;
            }           
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you just try...?

Comment: Since you have the code there, why don't you just hit F5 and see if it compiles? If it does, then you've answered your own question. If it doesn't, you've answered your own question :)

Comment: @dman2306 for compiling alone use `ctrl + shift + B` F5 will run the application :)

Comment: @Sakthivel of course. But you usually want to run your code too before declaring it works ;)

Comment: and what about the other part of the question?

Answer (score 3):

Your code does not **create** a struct; it merely **declares** a struct type but does not create any object of this type. Yes, you can declare nested types within a class. These can be interfaces, classes, structs, enums and delegates.

These types can even be used outside of the parent class if they are public. If your struct was public, you could use it like this from another class:

```
Program.Coffe c = new Program.Coffee(3, "bean", "country");
```

From within the `Program` class you can write:

```
Coffe c = new Coffee(3, "bean", "country");
```

If the nested type wants to access members of the parent class then it still needs a reference to an object of this parent type; i.e. the nesting is purely static.

Comment: Nested events? Im not sure if thats possible though

Comment: An event is a kind of property that can be asssigned a delelegate (with `+=`). It's not a type. It has a delegate type.

Comment: You forgot **interfaces** :-)